Need help figuring out how to pass props in React in this exercise from Udemy
okay so here is my app.jsx:
import { useState } from "react";
import "./index.css";
import "./App.css";
import Card from "./Card.jsx";
import About from "./About.jsx";
import Header from "./Header.jsx";

function App() {
  const properties = {
    language: "Javascript",
    framework: "React",
    skills: ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
  };
  const cardStyles = [
    { backgroundColor: "blue" },
    { backgroundColor: "green" },
    { backgroundColor: "black" },
    { backgroundColor: "red" },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <About styles={cardStyles} />
      <Card />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;


and then here is my About.jsx that i want to pass props to, both the cardStyles containing css styles so that the backgroundColor will be changeable for every instance of Card and also the skill prop, but for some reason i managed to make the skill prop work, but not the cardStyles thingy
import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card.jsx";
function About(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Frontend developer with a passion for building beautiful, functional and
        dynamic websites
      </p>
      <Card className="card1" skill="HTML" 
      cardStyle={props.styles[0]} />
      <Card className="card2" skill="CSS" 
      cardStyle={props.styles[1]} />
      <Card
        className="card3"
        skill="JavaScript"
        cardStyle={props.styles[2]}
      />
      <Card className="card4" skill="React" />
      <Card className="card5" skill="Node.js" />
    </div>
  );
}
export default About;

and lastly here is the Card.jsx component:
import React from "react";

import React from "react";

function Card(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="card" cardStyles={props.cardStyle}>
        <div>
          {props.skill} {props.cardStyle}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
export default Card;


And again, nothing is working as of right now with each component looking like this
I tried passing the props to About.jsx and Card.jsx, i expected things to work, i.e i expected to be able to define in each card your textcomponent instance which background color each div would have and which skill to display, but that's not what happened. The actual result is a blank page, no errors, just a blank page.

You are passing styles to <Card>:
<Card className="card1" skill="HTML" styles={props.styles[0]} />

But inside <Card> you're using
{props.skill} {props.cardStyles}

So that cardStyles doesn't exist and should be style

Demo where I've pass it as cardStyle to <Card> and use it in that component to style the <div>


const { useState } = React;

function Card(props) {
  return (
    <div className="card" style={props.cardStyle}>
      <div>
        {props.skill} {props.cardStyle.backgroundColor}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function About(props) {
 return (
    <div>
      <Card className="card1" skill="HTML" cardStyle={props.styles[0]} />
      <Card className="card4" skill="React" cardStyle={props.styles[1]} />
      <Card className="card5" skill="Node.js" cardStyle={props.styles[2]} />
    </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {

    const cardStyles = [
      { backgroundColor: "blue" },
      { backgroundColor: "green" },
      { backgroundColor: "black" },
      { backgroundColor: "red" },
    ];

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{'Example'}</h1>
            <About styles={cardStyles} />
        </div>
    )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>




Could you please elaborate? i think i'm not following.

I've added a demo. You passed some prop, but tried to use another name prop

I tried making these changes but it is still not working for me, i mean, the screen is no longer blank but the different divs are not changing color for me

Well we're not able to help without seeing the code. Did you ran my snipper to see it's working?

I mean didn't i post my code? besides i just copied and pasted your fixed code into my VScode so.. also i did run your code snippet and it works, but it doesnt work in my IDE for some reason

Yea but we don't know what you've changed right? Again, did you ran the snippet in my answer? Might be better to update the code in your question with what you currently have.

okay i changed the code in the OP to my current code with changes and whatnot

You're passing down cardStyle to the card, which is correct. The problem is how you're applying those styles to the child div. The div element doesn't accept a cardStyles prop. It only accepts a style prop.
Instead of this:
<div className="card" cardStyles={props.cardStyle}>

do this:
<div className="card" style={props.cardStyle}>


That didnt change anything, also why is styles supposed to work and not cardStyles? i don't see styles defined anywhere in the code?

React (and html) elements each have a standard set of props they accept. className and style are two of them. You can feed them any valid value (as defined by the docs). They don't need to be defined in your code, because they're already a part of the framework. It's a tool that's available to you.

so it isn't arbitrary? how do i know what is and what isn't arbitrary?

@JohannesPettersson The left side of the prop (ie 'style' in style={...}) belongs to the component you're using. If it's a div, it has a standard set of props (className, style, etc). If it's a custom component, you can give it custom props when the component is declared (ie function Custom(myProp), called like <Custom myProp='value' />)
